# How to stop spark file streaming job reading .tmp file from hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, spark-streaming

I am using spark file streaming for reading and process from Hadoop folder.
But It also stream .tmp file from Hadoop. Please help me to stream only completed file from Hadoop.

I am facing this issue.

Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 257.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 257.0 (TID 18830, Cassandra1, executor 1): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /mmi_traffic/listenerTransaction/2020/09/18/18/listenerTransaction.1600433700521.gz.tmp

Comment: Could you please paste the code snippet? You can use something like this 
df = spark \
    .readStream \ 
    .option("sep", ",") \ 
    .schema(userSchema) \ 
    .csv("path-to-hadoop-folder/*.<file format>")

Comment: //Folder Stracture: mmi_traffic/listenerTransaction/2020/09/18/18
String filePath = "hdfs://Master:9000/mmi_traffic/listenerTransaction/2020/*/*/*/";
JavaDStream<String> dStream = streamingContext.textFileStream(filePath).cache();

Comment: try changing it as given mmi_traffic/listenerTransaction/2020/09/18/18 String filePath = "hdfs://Master:9000/mmi_traffic/listenerTransaction/2020/*/*/*/*<file extension>"; JavaDStream<String> dStream = streamingContext.textFileStream(filePath).cache();

Comment: Exactly I am using this: hdfs://Master:9000/mmi_traffic/listenerTransaction/2020/*/*/*/; this working fine but sometime it get .tmp file so its cause the problem. When I try this : hdfs://Master:9000/mmi_traffic/listenerTransaction/2020/*/*/*/*.json; JavaDStream<String> dStream = streamingContext.textFileStream(filePath).cache(); it is not streaming any file.

Comment: Data sink to hdfs using flume and generates files like:                                     Sep 18 21:40 2 128 MB listenerTransaction.1600445100631.gz 
Sep 18 21:40 2 128 MB listenerTransaction.1600445400754.gz.tmp and streaming file by above code but spark stream also pick .tmp file

Comment: If you are reading a JSON file then you have to provide the schema. (I m doing it in scala)  val df = spark.readStream.schema("schema of json file").json("<path of input file folder")

Comment: Thank you so much, From last Friday night file streaming working fine. Not facing till now above problem. I have one more question. If streaming job stop/terminates  for 1 hour and start job again it process from latest stream file. Can we process from last processed file to continue.

Comment: Please use checkpointing in spark streaming-https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much